# How can I aling / synchronize two signals?

Tags: matlab, data-synchronization

I have two signals A and B (please, see them attached), which have been recorded from different devices with different sampling frequencies, on the same events.

I am trying to align both signals through cross-correlation methods. However, when using the alignsignals function, it does seem to actually delay even more the signals:

```
load A 
load B

% Sampling frequencies
Fs_A = 1000; % 
Fs_B = 1926; % 1925.93 Hz is the one provided by the device

% Resample signal A
A = resample(A, Fs_B, Fs_A);

% Plot of the two signals "delayed"
figure(1)
plot(A)
hold
plot(B*1000)

% Aling both signals
X = A; 
Y = B;

[Xa,Ya,D] = alignsignals(X,Y,[],'truncate');
figure(2) % plot both signals "aligned" 
plot(Xa)
hold
plot(Ya*1000)
```

I have also tried using xcorr function, with similar result:

```
load A 
load B

% Sampling frequencies
Fs_A = 1000; % 
Fs_B = 1926; % 1925.93 Hz is the one provided by the device

% Resample signal A
A = resample(A, Fs_B, Fs_A);

% Plot to visualize that one signal is delayed 
figure(1)
plot(A)
hold
plot(B*1000)

% Aling both signals using xcorr

[C,lag] = xcorr(A,B);
figure(2)
plot(lag,C);
[M,I] = max(C);
D = lag(I);
figure(3),plot(1:length(A), A, 'b',1+abs(D):length(B)+abs(D), B*1000, 'r'), title(' "Synchronised" signals ');
```

Am I making any mistake?

Thank you

Comment: Please, see an example with signals A and B:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0tbqk51fprtb7m7/AACU67xE3IIYQYfun9CWLf9fa?dl=0

Comment: whz dont you try to interpolate them on the same time axis with the max sampling frquency of the both ? it will be much easier

Comment: But length(A) and length(B) are different. How would this be worked around? Thank you

Comment: use `interp1(x,v,xq)` and in the xq vector use the same datapoints points for both signals with sampling frequency as 1926 , resultant vector for both the signals would have the same result